# Change the shell for cron job

Tags: unix, shell, cron, zsh

I have a zsh script that I would like to run via anacron every week.

It runs fine from an interactive bash shell, but when run by anacron, I am getting command not found errors and it looks like it is ignoring the shebang line.

The actual /etc/cron.weekly/ script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -x SCRIPT ] || exit 1

su NORMAL_USER SCRIPT
```

And the top line of the actual script is `#!/bin/zsh`

How can I get anacron to honor the shebang?  Would changing NORMAL_USER's login shell to zsh accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why it doesn't Work:**
The reason that it doesn't work is that su requires that you run the command from a terminal, and cron does not provide a terminal.

**Simple way to do it is using Vixie Cron:**
If you didn't mind using Vixie Cron I think the simplest thing to do would be to put the script in for that user by running the following as that user:

```
crontab -e
```

Then use `0 0 * * 0` as the time.

**If you want to use Anacron as a User:**
Anacron is helpful if you want to make sure the job doesn't get missed if the machine was off. To run as different user, specify a different anacron tab file and spool dir, put the following in the system cron to run as the specified user, `anacron -t /home/foo/etc/anacrontab -S /home/foo/var/spool/` and then edit that tab file to run the script.

There is also a [mini-howto](http://www.it.uc3m.es/marcos/doc/miniHOWTOs/miniHOWTO-Use_anacron_as_non-root_user.html), but this looks more complicated.

You will have to test these though to verify.  Lastly, remember this for future testing `run-parts --test /etc/cron.weekly`

Answer (score 1):

The shebang should take care of it. The first thing I look at when scripts don't run correctly under `cron` is environment variables such as `$PATH`. The `$PATH` for `cron` is much simpler than that of a user. You can set a `$PATH` in the `cron` script.

You can also hard-code the full path to all executables in your script.

If `zsh` is not at `/bin/zsh` you should get an invalid interpreter message, but you said it's running fine from a Bash prompt, so I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Currently the most portable shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` .  This works regardless of where `zsh` resides, in most distros.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the user's login shell to zsh makes this work.  I had been wanting to try out zsh as my login shell for awhile anyway.  Nothing like necessity to give you a push to do something.

Comment: Perhaps this works for `anachron`.  Generally, `chron` ignores the user's login shell. This behavior has been pretty consistent for me, from the 80's to now. I have never seen the login shell be used for cron jobs, in probably a dozen different forms of *nix including System III, System V, BSD, AIX, RHEL, and Ubuntu.